# ZedGraph RealTime Data Plotting C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

```
        public void DrawingPulseData(byte[] data)
        {

            // Make sure that the curvelist has at least one curve
            if (PulseControl.GraphPane.CurveList.Count <= 0)
                return;

            // Get the first CurveItem in the graph
            LineItem curve = PulseControl.GraphPane.CurveList[0] as LineItem;
            if (curve == null)
                return;

            // Get the PointPairList
            IPointListEdit list = curve.Points as IPointListEdit;
            // If this is null, it means the reference at curve.Points does not
            // support IPointListEdit, so we won't be able to modify it
            if (list == null)
                return;

            double time = (Environment.TickCount - tickStart) / 1000.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(time, (double)data[i]);
            }

            Scale xScale = PulseControl.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;

            if (time > xScale.Max - xScale.MajorStep)
            {
                xScale.Max = time + xScale.MajorStep;
                xScale.Min = xScale.Max - 30.0;
            }

            // Make sure the Y axis is rescaled to accommodate actual data
            PulseControl.AxisChange();
            // Force a redraw
            PulseControl.Invalidate();

            count = 0;
        }
```

Hi. I am using this method to draw real time data in zedgraph. `count` is length of incoming serial port data. This code works fine in timer(20ms) and draws data at each tick. However if i move this method into a class it does not work correctly. It draws too fast and wrong data.

```
public static void DrawingPulseData(byte[] data,ZedGraphControl zgc,int count, int TickStart)
```

I changed parameters like this after moving it into class. I changed PulseControl as zgc, tickstart as TickStart. I could not understand why it is not work same as the first code.

[image]

At the first picture,using code provided by @discomurray, i wrote this code statement out of the if's scopes. It gives me data like this.

```
   Scale xScale = zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;
   xScale.Max = now;
   xScale.Min = now - 30.0;
```

[image]

If i write the same code statement into if's scopes data looks like picture above. It is a 10 seconds record. I don't have such a data with my method.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that tickCount is the start time of the data buffer.

When adding the data to the list you need to change the x value (time) for each point in the list.

```
public static void DrawPulseData(byte[] data, ZedGraphControl zgc, int count, int tickStart)
{
    double now = Environment.TickCount / 1000.0;

    if (count != 0)
    {
        double span = (now - tickStart);

        double inverseRate = span / count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.add(tickStart + ((i+1) * inverseRate), data[i]);
        }
    }

    Scale xScale = zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale;
    xScale.Max = now;
    xScale.Min = now - 30.0;

    PulseControl.AxisChange();
    PulseControl.Invalidate();
}
```

as for drawing to fast, it will only go as fast as you tell it go.

Comment: Yea you assumed right it is the start time of data buffer. I tried your code. There is something wrong here. I copied Scale xScale = zgc.GraphPane.XAxis.Scale; and pasted it out of the if's scopes. However it draws something different. I uploaded some pictures related with your code.

Comment: I fixed the location of xScale initialization. how is data being filled? is it new data every call or the same buffer with more points in it? is the tickStart a new value call? are you using threading?

Comment: `int tickStart;` int Form_Load i use `tickStart = Environment.TickCount;` Then i run the method with timer tick (20ms). Maybe we should add your code this if statement. `if (time > xScale.Max - xScale.MajorStep) { xScale.Max = time + xScale.MajorStep; xScale.Min = xScale.Max - 30.0; }`